# Replace NAs in one DataFrame by value from another DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to coding and I have 2 dataframes I will post as following:

raw_data:

```
country_code      homicides_per_100k
     ABC               2.6
     ABB               nan
     ACC               nan
```

homi_set:

```
Country Code          year
     ABC               2.6
     ACC               11
     ABB               3.1
     ADD               0.5
```

The order and shape of 2 dataframes are not the same.

How can I use data from homi_set to replace nan in raw_data?

My code looks like this. it doesn't works:

```
for row, homicide in enumerate(raw_data['homicides_per_100k']):
    if homicide == "":
       country_code = raw_data.loc[row, 'country_code']
       homi_set_index = homi_set.index[homi_set['Country Code'] == country_code]
       homi_value = homi_set.loc[homi_set_index, '2014']
       raw_data.loc[row, 'homicides_per_100k'] = homi_value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_index` + `combine_first`. Set index makes it so the values are updated based on `country_code`. Combine first gives priority to non-null values in `raw_data` if there is a different value in `homi_set`.

```
raw_data = raw_data.set_index('country_code')
raw_data.combine_first(homi_set.set_index('Country Code')
                               .rename(columns={'year': 'homicides_per_100k'}))

print(raw_data)
              homicides_per_100k
country_code                    
ABC                          2.6
ABB                          3.1
ACC                         11.0
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. but I have an additional question: what if data for ABC are different in 2 dataframe? will "update" keep the one in raw_data?

Comment: @KaiyiZou. No, in that case it will overwrite the value. I updated the solution with `combine_first`, which is actually the logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Just Creating your dataframes
raw_data = pd.DataFrame([('ABC', 2.6), ('ABB', np.nan), ('ACC', np.nan)], columns=['Country_code', 'homicides_per_100k'] )
homi_set = pd.DataFrame([('ABC', 2.6), ('ACC', 11), ('ABB', 3.1), ('ADD', 0.5)], columns=['Country_code', 'year'] )
# Left Join
new_set = pd.merge(raw_data, homi_set, on='Country_code', how='left')
# condition on the column
new_set['homicides_per_100k'] = np.where(new_set['homicides_per_100k'].isnull(), new_set['year'], new_set['homicides_per_100k'] )
del new_set['year']
new_set
```

[image]